# sql order by name, numbers at the end

Tags: sql

maybe it is a very childish question.
can I order the record in that way that the values which begins with a number go to the end of the record?
for example these are the values in the database:

```
1
Bill
Andrew
```

to turn in this with a query:

```
Andrew
Bill
1
```

Comment: What type of system? There are some neat tricks with collation in MSSQL Server, if that is what you are using. Otherwise, unions will do what you need.

Answer (score 3):

```
ORDER BY -ISNUMERIC(a), a
```

Comment: I did something similar to this for columns that might *start* with a number but not be entirely numeric: `ORDER BY ISNUMERIC(LEFT(a, 1)), a` - in my case (SQL Server 2000) it sorted correctly when I left the result of ISNUMERIC positive.

Comment: This will hurt the performance, since isnumeric will need to be found for each item, before it can sort. It can be done in various ways to allow proper sorting, but all should have problems with performance.

Answer (score 0):

No, numbers will go to the end only if you will select DESC ordering - when letters go as "z..a". You probably should perform two queries - by letters and by numbers - and union results.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could to use two columns on your order by clause -- the first one not corresponding to a real DB columns, but based on some calculation :

- First, order by something that gives 1 for strings, and 2 for numbers

  - This will push all string to the beginning of the resultset
- And, then, order by the content of the column

Something like this (mostly pseudo-code) might help :

```
select *
from your_table
where ...
order by case when your_column >= '0' and your_column <= '9' then 2 else 1 end,
    your_column
```

The first part of the order by will ensure numbers are placed after non-numbers ; and the second part will just do a normal sort.

Note : I suppose the condition could be modified to use a function that determines if `your_column` contains a string or a number ; maybe there is some kind of `is_number` function, provided by your database system ?